# Where to add the partial class in the asp.net mvc5? In which folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried to add the partial class in the model folder of asp.net mvc folder structure. I have already added the class using entity framework. I want to create an partial class in the model folder, how to create?

Comment: You have to describe more thoroughly what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "I have already added the class using EntityFramework"? What do you mean by "override classes"?

Comment: i want to add the partial class in  the model folder but dont want to modified the autogenereated  classes

Comment: Make sure your newly created class has the same name and namespace as the autogenerated one. New class should be partial as well.

Comment: i tried but gives error class with same name already exist in the model folder...

Comment: both classes must have `partial` keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a file `Person.cs` with `Person` class in Model folder, you can add `Person.custom.cs` file.

`Person.cs`

```
namespace App.Model
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        // class content
    }
}
```

`Person.custom.cs`

```
namespace App.Model
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        // your content
    }
}
```